# grep regex for return numerical values in between string

Tags: regex, grep

so i'm running the linux command

```
ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -o -E "[0-9]+"
```

which should return just numerical values, the only problem it returns some unwanted numerical values from parts of results i dont want, i want only the numerical values between `-` and `.service` so in like `test-blah4-1321.service` i just want it to return `1321`. What am i missing here?

example

```
$ ls /etc/systemd/system
test.service                                test-blah4-1321.service  test-blah2.service                          test-blah5-1387.service  test-blah3-1521.service
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question is better suited to another network site like https://superuser.com/.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: As for GNU grep, the -P flag is the way to go. If, like me, you use a different version of grep (BSD grep), that has no -P flag, then you should look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> GNU grep has the -P option for perl-style regexes, and the -o option to print only what matches the pattern. These can be combined using look-around assertions (described under Extended Patterns in the [perlre manpage](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)) to remove part of the grep pattern from what is determined to have matched for the purposes of -o.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13472)

Applied to your example this would be:

```
echo test-blah4-1321.service | grep -oP '(?<=-)\d+(?=\.service)'
```

Answer (score 0):

when I need look ahead or look behind tests I usually switch to a Perl one-liner.
this should do the trick.

```
echo test-blah4-1321.service | perl -ne 'm/(?<=-)(\d+)(?=\.service)/g; print "$1\n";'
```

Comment: you can also do a grep with "-[0-9]+\.service" and then remove the context with sed... or just match what you want with another grep